# disable dock popping up with mouseover when in full screen

Tags: macos, fullscreen, osx-elcapitan

When the window is full screen, I don't want the dock to show up. A lot of times the application I am working with in full screen has some buttons and handles at the bottom of the page, and as soon as I move the mouse down to click on a button dock pops up and I click mistakenly on an item in dock. I don't remember I had this issue in previous versions of OSX but I am not too sure. I am currently on OSX El Capitan.

Comment: Is this an app that you are programming?

Answer (score 6):

You can set long interval to pop the dock up. Run this code in your terminal to pop the dock up in 15 seconds.

```
defaults write com.apple.Dock autohide-delay -float 15 && killall Dock
```

It works for me.

Comment: This does not work with High Sierra in full screen. The Dock is then disabled for normal desktops, but moving the cursor in full screen to the screen edge for 1s the  Dock will still pop up.